# Swift - Make func type explicit (in protocol)

Tags: swift, function, closures

Suppose, we have a protocol with `typealias`es like this:

```
// common closure types
typealias Action = () -> Void
typealias Consumer<T> = (T) -> Void

// here starts the fun
typealias AsyncAction = (Action?) -> Void
typealias AsyncGetter<T> = (Consumer<T>?) -> Void
typealias AsyncSetter<T> = (T, Action?) -> Void

// make compiler and you happy
typealias Foo = Void
typealias Bar = Void

protocol FooBarDatabaseAccess {
    func doSomething()
    func doSomethingAsync(completion: Action?)//: AsyncAction
    func getFooAsync(completion: Consumer<Foo>?)//: AsyncGetter<Foo>
    func getBarAsync(completion: Consumer<Bar>?)//: AsyncGetter<Bar>
    func setBarAsync(value: Bar, completion: Action?)//: AsyncSetter<Bar>
}
```

I would like to specify the function type similar to `let`/`var` declarations with a colon followed by its assignable type:

```
/* -- let/var -- */

// implicitly typed as String, determined from initial assignment
let implicitString = ""

// explicitly typed as String, though initialisation is omitted here
let explicitString: String


/* -- func -- */

// implicitly typed as () -> Void, determined from argument/return type(s)
func implicitAction()

// explicitly typed as Action, compiler should complain if it does not conform to the type (alias)
???
```

How can I achieve that?

A possible workaround is to transform it into a property declaration, but that is confusing:

```
var explicitAction: Action = { get }
```

Comment: What is confusing about your property declaration ? Seems like you nailed it :  the class that will implement it will be able to defines its "explicitAction" and the compiler will enforce the `Action` type

Comment: @AnderCover It is confusing because it suggests that it's a property rather than a function. Regarding the underlaying accessors: `get` further introduces an unwanted indirection and `set` does not apply to static code as in a `func`tions' body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `Action` is a `typealias` and not a type, swift can't differentiate them.

As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID361):

> After a type alias is declared, the aliased name can be used instead of the existing type everywhere in your program. The existing type can be a named type or a compound type. Type aliases do not create new types; they simply allow a name to refer to an existing type.

**Edit:** My bad, I thought you wanted to differentiate `() -> Void` and `Action`.
As far as I know, using a closure is the only way of doing this in swift.

```
typealias Foo = (Int) -> Void

protocol FooBar {
  var foo: Foo { get }
}

class FooBarBaz: FooBar {
  var foo: Foo = { intValue in
    // ...
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:** Additional information:

According to the [Grammar of a function declaration](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_function-declaration), the *only way* of declaring a function is to explicitly provide a `parameter-clause`, which require listing all parameters between parentheses:

> function-declaration → function-head function-name generic-parameter-clause<sub>opt</sub> **function-signature** generic-where-clause<sub>opt</sub> function-body<sub>opt</sub>
>
> function-signature → **parameter-clause** throws<sub>opt</sub> function-result<sub>opt</sub>
>
> parameter-clause → ( ) | ( parameter-list )

So apparently, it's not possible to declare a function with a type as signature without using a closure.

Comment: Sorry but that's not the issue I am facing. [I know very well that my "Action" is just an alias for "() -> Void", where "Void" itself is an alias to "()", making "Action" and "() -> ()" equivalent.]

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: If you can confirm somehow that the property transformation workaround *is* the only way to enforce the `func`s type, this will be the accepted answer

Comment: I filed an issue for the swift team: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8807